# Easiest way to update a Registry value?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, regedit

While using Linux I've grown accustomed to one-liners when I search online to fix annoying defaults. I know that these one liners *could* be very [dangerous](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Malicious_Linux_Commands) so I always make sure I know what they are doing before running them.

At the same time, I hate having to update windows registry keys because I need to open up regedit and navigate *The Tree*.

**Is there an easy way to edit a specific registry value?**

Something like:

```
regupdate path type newvalue
```

Comment: "I hate having to update windows registry keys because I need to open up regedit and navigate The Tree." - Besides all the answers below, why not switch to a better registry editor that allows you to directly jump to a specific key?

Comment: @Karan I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: [Does an alternative to regedit.exe exist?](http://superuser.com/questions/102112/does-an-alternative-to-regedit-exe-exist)

Comment: Considering that link is currently dead, I suppose the answer to that question is a no...

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As of the time of writing this, the accepted answer to this by David Marshall answers the question, but doesn't provide any detail beyond the link itself. In the interest of writing an answer that is both easily readable and invulnerable to potential link rot, I decided to write my own answer to the question.*

---

### How do I update the Windows Registry using the command line?

[The `reg` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), made available from as far back as Windows Server 2000, is used for this exact purpose, and the syntax is fairly simple to use.

#### To add a key

Run the following in a command line window:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey
```

...where *HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey* is the registry key that you want to create.

To add registry values and data along with keys, parameters are required. The `/v` parameter specifies the *name* of the value to be added, the `/t` parameter specifies the value *type*, and the `/d` parameter specifies the *data* to be contained within the value.

To add the key `HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey` with a `DWORD` value named
`LegacyDisable` that contains data of `000`:

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey /v LegacyDisable /t reg_dword /d 000
```

#### To delete a key

```
reg delete HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey
```

Parameters include `/v`, for deleting a particular value within a key instead of the key itself; `/ve`, to delete a key only if it contains no values; and `/f`, which overrides the command's default behaviour of waiting for user confirmation and forces the deletion.

To delete a value within a key:

```
reg delete HKLM\Software\Classes\MyKey /v ValueName
```

#### To compare two keys

The `reg` command's `compare` also allows you to compare two registry keys, listing the differences between the two by default:

```
reg compare HKCR\.doc HKCR\.docx
```

To change the default behaviour of listing differences, and instead list both the differences and similarities between two different keys, use the `/oa` parameter.

---

- When adding or modifying a registry key that contains spaces, make sure to wrap the key in quotes to avoid a bad syntax error.
- When referring to any of the registry hives in a key path - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`,
  `HKEY_USERS` and `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG` - the `reg` command allows    referencing them using their abbreviated versions - `HKLM`, `HKCR`,
  `HKCU`, `HKU`, and `HKCC` respectively - as demonstrated in the examples above.
- When a command is about to overwrite a currently-existing value, CMD defaults to prompting for confirmation. To bypass this confirmation, use the `/f` parameter to force the overwrite.

Answer (score 5):

[The Reg command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732643%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) does what you require.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! I'm surprised I didn't hear about it before.

Comment: Can you [edit] to improve your answer? Link only answers are discouraged, as they may go down at any time, leaving no content in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a .REG file to update it for you.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"RunOnceHasShown"=dword:00000001
"RunOnceComplete"=dword:00000001
```

Copy the code into a new Notepad window, and save the file with a `.REG` extention. When you run it (i.e. `START /w file.reg`, it will ask you to merge the contents

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to `Powershell` you could use its `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet.
[Here is an article on the subject.](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/12/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-easily-modify-registry-property-values.aspx)

Comment: PowerShell FTW!