# Changing Visual Effects settings through command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, visual-effects

Is there a way to change/modify the **Visual Effects** settings via command line?  For example, I want to control (enabling and disabling) on `Animate windows while minimizing and maximizing` option from command line.  I have seen many solutions that explains how to do this using Windows Registries, but I would like to know whether this can be controlled from command line?

[image: Visual Effects]

Comment: This may help (not answer, but help) http://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd

Answer (score 0):

To disable the effects

> sc stop uxsms

To enable the effects

> sc stop uxsms

You have to run it as Admin, you can create a batch scrip to do this,

This topic is discussed in detail from the below forum, give a try on it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516428/how-could-i-disable-windows-effects-through-batch

Comment: But this will disable/enable all the visual effect settings right?  Am looking for to enable only specific/selected options from the _Visual Effects_.  Moreover the provided link is explained using Windows Registries.