# Access denied when modifing value of registry key [run as admin & owner of key]

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, permissions, windows-registry

So i found out that i cant really modify value of the registry , whatever i do with my permissions i cant get it to work from command line (I need to do this from command line since i want to use other program to execute this) I do succeed when i try to manually change value from regedit window.

Image

[image]

I run on windows 10 64bit , im the owner of the key with  full permissions and administrator on this account.

**Any idea why i get Access denied?**  I cant seem to figure this out.

Command :

> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render{d348b8e8-3118-4a9c-9b43-422647b555ca}\FxProperties
>   /f /v "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4" /t REG_DWORD /d "1"

Comment: The value already exists? Have you tried deleting it first then adding it?

Comment: @DavidPostill Value exists already, im looking to overwrite it  - parameter /f forces it to overwrite , based on http://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd  .Havent tryed to delete anything, bud is that really  reason to throw access denied?

Comment: I know about `/f`. I was curious if you get the same error trying to delete it.

Comment: @DavidPostill No idea, im scared to delete this value (cant restart this system atm) , its system value  and i dont wanna mess up my audio , its value for Loudness  equalization. 1 enabled , 0 disabled

Comment: put the reg add code in a text file, then change the extension to .reg, then right click on it and select Merge, does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little typo: double quote missing:

```
reg add "HKLM\ … \FxProperties  /f /v …
                              |<-------- here
reg add "HKLM\ … \FxProperties" /f /v …
```

For a wonder, `reg query` and `reg add` raise another error in case of such simple syntax mistake:

```
==> reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test Key /v "{testval},1"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

==> reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test Key" /v "{testval},1"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Test Key
    {testval},1    REG_DWORD    0x1


==> reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test Key /f /v "{testval},1"  /t REG_DWORD /d "1"
ERROR: Access is denied.

==> reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Test Key" /f /v "{testval},1"  /t REG_DWORD /d "1"
The operation completed successfully.

==>
```

Comment: Yes that and one other typo i had in the key "path" was the cause i got that error, too bad the error name didnt really helped me to realize that :) thanks JosefZ.