# How to append a registry key value that has spaces in it?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry

I found the following page ([How do I modify the data of an existing registry key value name from cmd?](https://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd)) and it was extermely helpful, but I have a further question.

My PATH has a value that includes "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\", and I'd like to add "P:\SQL" to it.  When I run the script below, my PATH will then look like "C:\Program;P:\SQL".  What needs to be modified so my PATH will look like "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;P:\SQL"?

Here is what I have:

```
for /F "skip=2 tokens=3" %%r in ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path') do set oldVal=%%r    
echo previous=%oldVal%    
set newVal=%oldVal%;P:SQL    
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %newVal% /f
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use `/v` not `/ve` to start with.

Comment: Why are you using the registry to set the path?

Comment: DavidPostill, I had tried with only '/V' but it didn't work either.

We are deploying a new software to 700 computers and I need to add P:\SQL to the PATH for  modules of that app to access data, and I don't think that sending a tech to 700 computers is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I add a value to my `PATH`?

> My `PATH` has a value that includes `"c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\"`, and I'd like to add `"P:\SQL"` to it

Why are you reading/writing the registry?

Just use `setx` to add a value to your `PATH`:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;P:\SQL" /m
```

Note:

- `/m` Set the variable in the system environment `HKLM`.

  (The default is the local environment `HKCU`)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [setx](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) - Set environment variables permanently, SETX can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine (HKLM) or currently logged on user (HKCU).
- [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

---

Comment: Why I was using the registry?  Because I know just enough to get myself in trouble. :)

You fixed the issue.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to tamper the registry you do so the following, but at your **own risk**

```
@echo off
set new_value=;P:/SQL     ::set the new value here

set key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"
for /F "delims= skip=2" %%r in ('reg query %key% /v "Path"') do set old_value=%%r
set old_value=%old_value:    Path    REG_SZ    =%
set new_value=%old_value%%new_value%
reg add %key% /v "Path" /d "%new_value%" /f
```

I must say, this is rather very crude way to do this. **Always remember to take a backup of the registry before altering it**.