# Windows 10 editing internet options via command line

Tags: windows-10, command-line, proxy

I am wanting to see and edit the proxy settings that are found in the internet options of windows. I have tried:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

but that returns nothing when there is a proxy in the internet options in the control panel.

If I use

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | findstr ProxyServer AutoConfigURL
```

Then it will spit out the current proxy and port in the internet options which is what I need. Is there a way to return and/or add exceptions to the proxy? In the internet options when clicking "Advanced" you can enter exceptions separated by semicolons (;). Is there a way to do this through the command line? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my computer, proxy exceptions are stored in a value named "ProxyOverride" in the same directory.

You can get it with this command :

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /V ProxyOverride
```

You can use the RED ADD command to add this value.

It's a REG_SZ value. The syntax of the value is :

```
exception1;exception2;exception3
```

If you can't find this value, try to add it from the GUI and find where it is by searching the exception added in the regedit.

Comment: Ok, using the command you gave me it does print the exceptions. Is there a way about going to add to these exceptions from the command line? I'm unsure of the syntax tbh. I do see a ProxyBypass REG_DWORD within ZoneMap folder of Internet Settings?

Comment: You can use REG ADD command to overwrite the value. The syntax should be the following (NOT TESTED) : `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /t REG_SZ /v ProxyOverride /d "exception1;exception2;exception3" /f`. You must be warn when editing registry. An error in modification can impact the integrity of your computer.

Comment: Thank you! That worked but is there a way to add to the list rather than overwrite the current list of exceptions? Don't know if that is an option but would be extremely helpful!

Comment: It can be achieve by using a script a bit more complex. Example here : https://superuser.com/questions/607572/how-do-i-modify-the-data-of-an-existing-registry-key-value-name-from-cmd. Don't forget to mark the answer as valid if it allow you to solve your problem.